# Should the protection filter be before or after the full bridge rectifier in a Tesla coil?

Tags: tesla-coil

I'm making a basic spark gap Tesla coil.  I would like to use a Terry filter to protect the neon sign transformer (NST.)

I also have a full bridge rectifier to convert the output of the NST to DC.

Would it be OK to put the Terry filter after the rectifier so that both the NST and the rectifier are protected?

Comment: It's unclear what you are proposing. Please post a circuit within your question and explain what a terry filter is. Data sheet links to the neon sign transformer and bridge rectifier are probably also needed.

Comment: Best find a dedicated Tesla Coil forum. There's a lot of know-how that they will have to hand, the generalists here are not au fait with Terry filters and where they need to go. BTW, a 'basic spark gap coil' uses AC, not rectified DC.